# SQL select multiple max rows where ID is same

Tags: sql

i've struggled again and again on this, but can't get it to work. been on these forums for hours now... Data set:

```
Row Date            AccountID   Column 1    
1   21/02/2013 0:30     A0M8FA1003YP    .       
2   21/02/2013 0:30     A0M8FA1003YP    .       
3   21/02/2013 0:30     A0M8FA1003YP    .       
4   24/09/2007 12:00    A0M8FA1003YP    .       
5   24/09/2007 12:00    A0M8FA1003YP    .       
6   24/09/2007 12:00    A0M8FA1003YP    .       
7   12/02/2009 12:00    A023123332YP    .       
8   24/09/2003 12:00    A023123332YP    .       
9   24/09/2003 12:00    A023123332YP    .       
10  24/09/2003 12:00    A023123332YP    .
```

I want to return the max value of the date column, but not just return a single row, but any rows that match that max value. I.e. In the above set I want to return rows 1, 2, 3 and 7 (all columns for the rows as well).

```
Row Date                AccountID       Column 1    
1   21/02/2013 0:30     A0M8FA1003YP    .       
2   21/02/2013 0:30     A0M8FA1003YP    .       
3   21/02/2013 0:30     A0M8FA1003YP    .   
7   12/02/2009 12:00    A023123332YP    .
```

I've got thousands of rows, and the number of matching rows to return for each ACCOUNTID will vary, some 1, some 2, some 10. Please help me!!!

**UPDATE**
Have also tried this

```
Select max(ASS_SCH_DATE) over (partition by AccountID), 
       AccountID, 
       ASS_SCH_DATE, 
       ACCOUNTID 
from #Temp3 
order by #Temp3.ACCOUNTID
```

Results still showing extra rows.

```
(No column name)            ASS_SCH_DATE                ACCOUNTID
2013-02-21 00:30:00.000     2013-02-21 00:30:00.000     A0M8FA1003YP
2013-02-21 00:30:00.000     2013-02-21 00:30:00.000     A0M8FA1003YP
2013-02-21 00:30:00.000     2013-02-21 00:30:00.000     A0M8FA1003YP
2013-02-21 00:30:00.000     2007-09-24 12:00:00.000     A0M8FA1003YP
2013-02-21 00:30:00.000     2007-09-24 12:00:00.000     A0M8FA1003YP
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: hi, i've tried everything including things such as:

SELECT *,C_ENDORSEMENTID+'-'+ACCOUNTID as 'C3' into #Temp3
FROM #Temp2 WHERE ASS_SCH_DATE IN (SELECT MAX(ASS_SCH_DATE) FROM #Temp2 group by ACCOUNTID) order by ACCOUNTID

Comment: Thanks very much team! I've stuck with justins as there's very few lines involved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a9e2/1)**

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Date = (SELECT MAX(t2.Date)
                 FROM Table1 t2
                 WHERE t2.AccountID = t1.AccountID)
```

Result:

```
| ROW |                            DATE |    ACCOUNTID |
--------------------------------------------------------
|   1 | February, 21 2013 00:30:00+0000 | A0M8FA1003YP |
|   2 | February, 21 2013 00:30:00+0000 | A0M8FA1003YP |
|   3 | February, 21 2013 00:30:00+0000 | A0M8FA1003YP |
|   7 | February, 12 2009 12:00:00+0000 | A023123332YP |
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, this works as well: Amended Script:

SELECT t1.*
FROM #Temp3 t1
WHERE t1.ASS_SCH_DATE = (SELECT MAX(t2.ASS_SCH_DATE)
                 FROM #Temp3 t2
                 WHERE t2.ACCOUNTID = t1.ACCOUNTID)
                 order by ACCOUNTID

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where date in (select max(date) from table)
```

Comment: thanks bunny, but this only selects the first instance for the first account in the table. There are thousands of ACCOUNT ID sets and related date values.

Comment: just look if you have all the account ID's related to exact max same date

Comment: Hi Bunny, sorry, can't understand that. I've updated the title to show a few more rows of the table so you get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Windows functions are what you are looking for:

```
Select row,max(date) over (partition by AccountID) As max_date, AccountID, 
Column1 from table where max_date = date;
```

Comment: Hi again - i'm still seeing rows that should be there, i've updated the topic with new results

Comment: Updated my answer, try now.

Comment: does it now serves your purpose??

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select * from tablename where date in (select max(date) from table group by AccountID)
```

Please see the [sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2a9e2/2).It is giving same output that you are expecting.

Comment: Hi RS, have tried it, still getting same results (see OP)

Query is: select * from #Temp3 where ASS_SCH_DATE in (select max(ASS_SCH_DATE) from #Temp3 group by AccountID). 

Could there be something else getting in the way here?

Comment: I have added  link showing same output that you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Ranks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx):

```
SELECT  AccountID, 
        ASS_SCH_DATE, 
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ASS_SCH_DATE ORDER BY AccountID) DateRank
FROM YourTable
WHERE DateRank = 1
```

This way you can also select highest ranks, second highest etc...

Comment: Thanks Avi, it works, amended script.

WITH RankedData AS
(
 SELECT  *,
   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNTID ORDER BY ASS_SCH_DATE desc) as Ranking
 FROM #Temp3
)
SELECT RankedData.Ranking, RankedData.*
FROM RankedData 
WHERE RankedData.Ranking = 1 
ORDER BY RankedData.ACCOUNTID

Answer (score 0):

Easy...

Being 'dummy' your table, I would write:

```
SELECT dummy.*
FROM
  (
      SELECT MAX(Date) Date, AccountID
      FROM dummy
      GROUP BY AccountID
  ) max_date
    INNER JOIN dummy
    ON(
          dummy.Date      = max_date.Date
      AND dummy.AccountID = max_date.AccountID
    )
```

Or, using modern, more semantical syntax:

```
WITH max_date(Date, AccountID)
AS
(
  SELECT MAX(Date) Date, AccountID
  FROM dummy
  GROUP BY AccountID
)
SELECT dummy.*
FROM
  max_date
    INNER JOIN dummy
    ON(
          dummy.Date      = max_date.Date
      AND dummy.AccountID = max_date.AccountID
    )
```

Comment: I've created dummy as:

CREATE TABLE dummy(
  Row        INT,
  Date       DATETIME,
  AccountID  VARCHAR(255),
  [Column 1] VARCHAR(255)
)
GO

insert into dummy values(1   , '20130221 00:30', 'A0M8FA1003YP', '.')
insert into dummy values(2   , '20130221 00:30', 'A0M8FA1003YP', '.')
insert into dummy values(3   , '20130221 00:30', 'A0M8FA1003YP', '.')
insert into dummy values(4   , '20070924 12:00', 'A0M8FA1003YP', '.')
insert into dummy values(5   , '20070924 12:00', 'A0M8FA1003YP', '.')
insert into dummy values(6   , '20070924 12:00', 'A0M8FA1003YP', '.')
...